# JavaFX Button alignment bug

Tags: java, javafx, alignment

I've just come across what I believe to be a potential bugs when setting the alignment of buttons. Firstly, I'd like to clearly state that it's possible that setting the alignment of the button is not the right approach here, however, I want to outline that I think there still may be a possible bug.

I noticed it in an application that had a tab pane, with buttons on two consecutive tabs. When I set the alignment of a button on one tab, it caused buttons on another tab to behave strangely such that the text aligned left on the button but then centralises when you hover over it.

I have simplified this behaviour to the following JavaFX application, here is the start method:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Button b1 = new Button("A button");
        b1.setPrefSize(120, 50);

        Button b2 = new Button("Another button");
        b2.setPrefSize(120, 50);
        b2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); //try comment this line out

        TabPane tp = new TabPane();
        Tab t1 = new Tab("First tab", b1);
        Tab t2 = new Tab("Second tab", b2);
        tp.getTabs().addAll(t1, t2);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(tp);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
}
```

If you run the application, you will notice the text on the button on the first tab called "A button" is left-aligned, but when you hover over it, it aligns centrally.

If you comment out the line of code: b2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); then this behaviour stops. So I do not understand why setting the alignment of another button instance on a separate tab is having this affect on button b1?